# Web API and rendering template, should they in the same function call?

Tags: python, flask, asp.net-web-api

I am new on web development. 
I am now implementing a simple create/edit user form with a submit button.

I would like to know the better practice to implement this.

I have already define this kind of web api

```
URL           Method    Description
/users/       GET   Gives a list of all users
/users/       POST  Creates a new user
/users/<id>   GET   Shows a single user
/users/<id>   PUT   Updates a single user
/users/<id>   DELETE    Deletes a single user
```

**My first approach:**

i create  two new "/user/add" and "/usr/edit" function, 
which similar to

```
app.route("/users/edit")
def edit_user(){
    ....
    ....
    call the internal api /user/ with a "put" method
    ....
    render_template("edit.html")
```

when I click the submit the button, the i call the above internal api /users/ ,method=PUT, 
and render the final template.

**My second approach:**

in my internal api /user/, i try to read the http header to see if i want a html template or json text and return back to user

Say, again when i want to create a edit form, instead of calling /user/edit , i call /user/, with a PUT method

```
def put(self, id):
    //see the header of that request
    if header == html
       render_template("edit.html", .....)
    if header == json
       update the record
```

#

my question , basically, i don't know if "/user/add" "/user/edit" route is necessary to make a form, or we can just simple embedded into /user/ api with different "post" or "put" method.

the idea is coming from here , from [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/), pluggable view, which i am wondering how to make a better implementation

Or is that a better way to do it???

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would choice your first approach because than your URLs are clear and logical. Also you split your frontend (Website with forms) and backend (API) which is in testing very helpful. A normal web browser makes only GET and POST requests to a website so it is very difficult to render template by a PUT request for the user because the user is normally not able to start a put request.

Comment: did you implement this kind of thing before, can u share some experiences?

Comment: Nope. I would create a form with flask-wtf with validation. At the submit of this form you can send the data over a new http request to your internal api with the flask test client or the requests python module.